# MongoDB GridFS Size Limit

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I am using MongoDB as a convenient way of storing a dataset as a series of columns where there is a document that stores the values for a given column and another document that stores the details of the detaset, and a mapping to the other documents with the associated column values. The issue I'm now facing as things get bigger is that I can no longer store the entire column in a single document.

I'm aware that there is also the GridFS option, the only downside is that I believe it stores the files as blobs meaning I would lose random access to a chunk of the column, or the value at a specified index, something that was incredibly useful from the document store, however I may not ahve any other option.

So my question is: does GridFS also impose an upper limit on the size of documents and if so does anyone know what this is. I've looked in hte docs and haven't found anything, but it may be I'm not looking in the correct place or that there is a limit but it's not well documented.

Thanks,
Vackar

Comment: You should probably try to rethink your schema and have smaller documents.

Comment: Why are you using MongoDB for this? You're loosing all the advantages of the DB if you're storing data in a binary blob inside of GridFS. A GridFS file likely has an upper bounds declared somewhere, but I'd bet you'll run out of disk space long before you encounter it.

Comment: WiredPrairie -> Yes I take your point. Ideally i'd like to keep it stored in a native format where you can access all of the db features, however mongodb documents may no longer be a viable solution for me.

Answer (score 4):

### GridFS

Per the [GridFS documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/):

```
Instead of storing a file in an single document, GridFS divides a file
into parts, or chunks, and stores each of those chunks as a separate
document. By default GridFS limits chunk size to 256k. GridFS uses
two collections to store files. One collection stores the file chunks,
and the other stores file metadata.
```

GridFS will allow you to store arbitrarily large files however this really won't help your use case.  A file in GridFS will effectively be a large binary blob and you will not get any of the benefits of structured documents and indexing.

### Schema Design

The fundamental challenge you have is your approach to schema design.  If you are creating documents that are likely to grow beyond the 16Mb document limit, these will also have a significant impact on your database storage and fragmentation as the documents grow in size.

The appropriate solution would be to rethink your schema approach so that you do not have unbounded document growth.  This probably means flattening the array of "columns" that you are growing so it is represented by a collection of documents rather than an array.

A better (and separate) question to ask would be how to refactor your schema given the expected data growth patterns.

Comment: ***GridFs used to store larger file beyond 16mb*** But the ***BSON limit 16MB*** . Could you please elaborate why this? If  BSON limit is 16MB then how Gridfs can changed it?

Comment: @DarkKnight This is mentioned in the documentation quote: "Instead of storing a file in an single document, GridFS divides a file into parts, or chunks, and stores each of those chunks as a separate
document. By default GridFS limits chunk size to 256k.". You can add some metadata to improve searchability, but GridFS is generally most useful when you want to store large binary data. If your data model encourages documents that may approach or exceed the 16MB document limit, you need to rethink your schema design. Documents with unbounded growth are a performance anti-pattern.